# Defer updating element that is bound to a list

Tags: c#, binding

please I need help with the following scenario.
I have a binding list that has entity objects. I am passing the current entity object to a save form that is used to update the entity object passed as a parameter. This save form reads the properties of the entity object class and display controls accordingly. Each of these controls is bound to a property of the entity object. Whenever I change a control value, the corresponding entity property will be updated which will update the entity object in the entity list. 
What I need is to apply the changes on the entity object in my save form only after an update button is clicked. 
One way around is to make a copy of the entity object before passing it to the save form. But making a deep copy of an object is costly as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class that will resemble the entity and will act as a buffer for the properties on the update form. When the user click's update read all the properties from the buffer class and pass them to the entity and then save it to DB.

Comment: This will be as costly as making a deep copy of my entity object.  Assume that my entity contains a list of references X where each X is itself a list of references Y. I will have to copy all these properties from my buffer class. Adding buffer class may also make the code harder to maintain since every change in my entity class should be applied to my buffer class.